# c# LDAP connection to domain outside forest

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryentry

I am trying to write some code to write objects into Active Directory using c#.  I have a test Domain Controller that is not a member of the domain or forest that my laptop writing the code is a member of.  I have tried the following substitutions for username and server in all combinations but when I get to the line

```
adobject = myLdapConnection.Children.Add(value, type);
```

I get back the error

*The username or password is incorrect.*

Why am I getting this error if the username and password are correct?

testuser is a domain admin.  I can verify that it is correct with a program like Softerra LDAP Browser that connects to the server fine and lets me create objects.

```
//string username = "CN=testuser,CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=com";
//string username = "testuser";
//string username = "AD\\testuser";

//string server="LDAP://10.10.10.10:389";
//string server="LDAP://10.10.10.10";

string server = "LDAP://10.10.10.10:389";
string basedn = "ou=testou,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=com";
string username = "CN=testuser,CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=com";
string password="plaintextpassword";
DirectoryEntry myLdapConnection = new DirectoryEntry(server+"/"+basedn,username,password,AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
string value="ou=testsubou,ou=testou,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=com";
string type="organizationalUnit";
DirectoryEntry adobject = myLdapConnection.Children.Add(
                                   value, type);
adobject.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: Should `myLdapConnection` be `ldapConnection` in your code?

Comment: Changed the code to reflect.  Typo on my part when typing in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Username should be in "normal" format instead of `"CN=testuser,CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=com";`. Normal means `DOMAIN\USER` or `user@DOMAIN.XXX`

Comment: I thought that too, but someone from Microsoft said differently: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/557b0e22-e13a-44fc-a794-ecef01bf170a/directoryentryusername-is-domain-fqdn-supported-in-user-name?forum=winserverDS

Comment: It's probably worth a test anyway though.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I never used DN as a login. If it is working I will learn something new :D

Comment: Both DN and the normal DOMAIN\USER do not appear to work, but the user@DOMAIN.XXX does.

Comment: Just as a note, I also had to leave off basedn if I wanted to use the full dn when creating the OU.